# Why does the file import fail when using DBeaver?

Tags: mysql, amazon-s3, import, path, dbeaver

When I try to import a CSV from Amazon S3 buckets as follows

```
LOAD DATA FROM S3 's3-eu-west-2://csv-files/OCN04.txt'  
    INTO TABLE `OCN`  
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'  
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'  
    IGNORE 1 ROWS
    ;
```

it fails in DBeaver, while it had been working with Mysql-Workbench.

Comment: try with LOAD DATA INFILE FROM S3 's3://<your-file-location>/<filename>.csv'

Comment: Thanks, but no. That doesn't work either

Answer (score 1):

On DBeaver you can import data from a file into a table [with the GUI](https://dbeaver.com/docs/dbeaver/Data-transfer/#import-data).

Right-click on the table and select "import data" menu.

[image: Import Data Capture]

Then select the file to import. If needed, adjust the mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Load data infile works but i am guessing the file path is the issue here. I'm guessing that dbeaver only reads file from a specific directory. To know the specific/default directory, you try running the above code with simply the name of your file (i.e. 'OCN04.txt'). The error message will show the file path. Save your txt file in that directory and try running your code again.

The above method works for me.